# Using write to print floating point numbers

Tags: c, floating-point

The `write` function does not print a floating point number in the following code:

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main(){

    float f = 4.5;

    write(1,&f,sizeof float);

    return 0;
}
```

This results in:

```
�@
```

Whereas:

```
int main(){

    char *c = "Hello world";

    write (1,c,strlen(c)+1);

    return 0;
}
```

Prints `Hello world` as expected.

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: hmmm, is printf not an option, or are you just doing exercises?  write is just going to put the raw binary on the screen, while the floating point format needs to be interpreted.

Comment: printf is not an option, because this will be written in mips assembly

Comment: @Tom: Availability of a function doesn't depend on the CPU architecture.

Comment: @Kenny I know, but I dont want to call C from assembly.

Comment: @Tom: `write` is already kind-of a C function (yeah it maybe a kernel call, but I think most kernels do have a `printf`).

Comment: @Kenny. Yes I know. From assembly im calling directly to sys_write, via syscall. Dont want to call any user -space C code from my assembly. If its in the kernel, I can live with it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`write` outputs the bytes in the binary representation of the floating-point number. Those bytes do not even always correspond to readable characters, let alone to the textual representation of the number itself.

I guess you want to convert the number to human-readable text. That's what `printf` is for:

```
printf("%f", f);
```

Comment: Yes, but I cant use printf, must use write. So I guess i'll have to convert them to bytes ?

Comment: You can use sprintf, but that's just stupid. Why do you have to use write?

Comment: Because I have to move this to assembly, using SYS_WRITE

Comment: I ended up avoiding the write from assembly and inserting the floating point values in an extern array. Then print them from C.

Comment: If this is linked to the C standard library, you can also call `printf` from your assembly. But I guess that calling it from C is easier :)

Answer (score 3):

Converting floating point numbers to strings is a far from trivial problem.  See the famous [Excel 2007 bug](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2007/09/26b.html) for an example of how even Microsoft got that wrong.  You should use a library function such as [`snprintf(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf) to convert the float to a string, and then you can use `write(2)` to write out the string:

```
float f = 4.5f;
char buf[64];
snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%g", f);
write(1, buf, strlen(buf));
```

Comment: Thanks , this gave me a nice idea.

Comment: I ended up avoiding the write from assembly and inserting the floating point values in an extern array. Then print them from C.

Answer (score 0):

Using `write` introduces dependency on endianness. So you might have to reverse the byte order when you read the file back in.

Otherwise, your code is perfectly fine. Did you try writing another program to read back in the same fashion, and compare the results?

The entire point of using `write` is to avoid conversion to text.

```
int main(){

    float f;

    read(0,&f,sizeof(float) );
    printf( "%f", (double) f );

    return 0;
}
```

Execute from the shell as

```
write_test | read_test
```

Answer (score 0):

You cat use obsolete function gcvt() to convert the case with float to your case with string:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
        char buffer[11];

        gcvt(3.1425, 3, buffer);
        buffer[10]=0;

        write(1, buffer,strlen(buffer)+1);

        return 0;
}
```

But snprintf() is preferable to use.

Answer (score 0):

Look around for an implementation of `ftoa`.  As mentioned by others, converting from floating point to a string representation is not a trivial task.  Attempting to do so from assembly will be quite a challenge.